# Python with Gtk3 not setting unicode properly

Tags: unicode, python-3.x, clipboard, gtk3

I have some simple code that isn't working as expected. First, the docs say that `Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY).set_text()` should be able to accept only one argument with the length argument option, but it doesn't work (see below). Finally, pasting a unicode `°` symbol breaks setting the text when trying to retrieve it from the clipboard (and won't paste into other programs). It gives this warning:

> Gdk-WARNING **: Error converting selection from UTF8_STRING

```
>>> from gi.repository.Gtk import Clipboard
>>> from gi.repository.Gdk import SELECTION_PRIMARY
>>> d='\u00B0'
>>> print(d)
°
>>> cb=Clipboard
Clipboard
>>> cb=Clipboard.get(SELECTION_PRIMARY)
>>> cb.set_text(d) #this should work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-6-b563adc3e800>", line 1, in <module>
    cb.set_text(d)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: set_text() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

>>> cb.set_text(d, len(d))
>>> cb.wait_for_text()

(.:13153): Gdk-WARNING **: Error converting selection from UTF8_STRING
'\\Uffffffff\\Uffffffff'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for `Gtk.Clipboard`

It looks like the method `set_text` needs a second argument. The first is the text, the second is the length of the text. Or if you don't want to provide the length, you can use -1 to let it calculate the length itself.

> gtk.Clipboard.set_text
>
> ```
> def set_text(text, len=-1)
> ```
>
> text : a string.
>
> len  : the length of text, in bytes, or -1, to calculate the length.

I've tested it on Python 3 and it works with `cb.set_text(d, -1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since GTK version 3.16 there is a easier way of getting the clipboard. You can get it with the get_default() method:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib, Gio

display = Gdk.Display.get_default()
clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get_default(display)
clipboard.set_text(string, -1)
```

also for me it worked without

```
clipboard.store()
```

Reference: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Clipboard.html#Gtk.Clipboard.get_default

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.4. this is only needed for GtkEntryBuffers. In case of GtkTextBuffer `set_text` works without the second parameter.

example1 works as usual:

```
settinginfo = 'serveradres = ' + server + '\n poortnummer = ' + poort
GtkTextBuffer2.set_text(settinginfo)
```

example2 needs extra parameter len:

```
ErrorTextDate = 'choose earlier date'
GtkEntryBuffer1.set_text(ErrorTextDate, -1)
```

Comment: After checking my code I find that the extra parameter was only needed for empty textbuffers. If the buffer is pre-filled with an initial text the len paramter is not asked for. This is the case when building a GUI with Glade and pr-filling a text in the designated textblok.